# Show Product's Custom Attributes to Homepage or static page

Tags: magento, custom-attributes

I want to `echo` the custom attributes to any other page, except `Product Page` or `Category Listing`

Comment: Could be a little more specific

Comment: I created a `new attribute` named `power`, I want to show it at homepage `featured product` slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting custom attribute in nearly any page can be done as following (in PHP):

```
$product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId(); // note that this changes depending on how you load your product
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$value = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'your_power_attribute_id', $storeId);
echo $value;
```